# Method for printing CLI11 help_text

Tags: c++, parsing, command-line-parser

I've search high and low and can't find this. What is the [CLI11](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11) method to print out the help. I want to be able to show the user the help when they've entered incorrect info.

Also, does CLI11 throw an exception when no option are given? If not, how do you tell how many options have been given?

Comment: What is cli11??

Comment: @Alan: Apparently it's an argument parsing library. I added a link, straight from a web search.

Comment: CLI11 is a command line parsing package. And yes, I already l know about that page about using CLI11, not what CLI11 method is used to progmatically output the help text for the tool you are building. You can use the -h, --help command line options to output the help text on your tool. But I what to progmatically output that text from inside my tool.

Comment: @rtcdude: i guessed that you knew that page I added the link as a courtesy to other readers of the question who might not have been familiar with it, such as the person who asked about it.

Answer (score 4):

## Too long, didn't read

```cpp
// App::help() returns a std::string
std::cerr << app::help() << std::flush;
```

## Not detailed enough, more information please

### How `App::exit(...)` leads to help text being emitted

[Here's the member function](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11/blob/516f603857d10fa2726a278d9059b2455ba97c97/include/CLI/App.hpp#L1314) `App::exit` from `CLI/App.hpp`.

We can see that a `std::ostream` object `out` is used in conjunction with [`App::help()`](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11/blob/516f603857d10fa2726a278d9059b2455ba97c97/include/CLI/App.hpp#L1506) and `App::help("", AppFormatMode::All)`,

```cpp
    int exit(const Error &e, std::ostream &out = std::cout, std::ostream &err = std::cerr) const {

        /// Avoid printing anything if this is a CLI::RuntimeError
        if(e.get_name() == "RuntimeError")
            return e.get_exit_code();

        if(e.get_name() == "CallForHelp") {
            out << help();
            return e.get_exit_code();
        }

        if(e.get_name() == "CallForAllHelp") {
            out << help("", AppFormatMode::All);
            return e.get_exit_code();
        }

        if(e.get_name() == "CallForVersion") {
            out << e.what() << std::endl;
            return e.get_exit_code();
        }

        if(e.get_exit_code() != static_cast<int>(ExitCodes::Success)) {
            if(failure_message_)
                err << failure_message_(this, e) << std::flush;
        }

        return e.get_exit_code();
    }
```

### `App::help(...)` itself

`App::help(...)` itself has the following prototype:

```cpp
std::string help(std::string prev = "", AppFormatMode mode = AppFormatMode::Normal) const
```

### Demonstration usage

We can therefore use `App::help` (Compiler Explorer [demo short url](https://godbolt.org/z/4fMPsfjaa), [demo full url](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27//+C%2B%2B+Standard+Library%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0A//+3rd+party+libraries%0A%23include+%22CLI/CLI.hpp%22%0A%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++CLI::App+app%7B%22Demonstration+app%22%7D%3B%0A%0A++++//+Assigning+to+string+for+demonstrative+purposes%0A++++const+std::string+help_text+%3D+app.help()%3B%0A++++std::cerr+%3C%3C+help_text+%3C%3C+std::flush%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:49.736644093303234,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%270%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:clang1000,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:cli11,ver:%27200%27)),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O0+-g+-ggdb+-fsanitize%3Daddress,undefined+%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+clang+10.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.26335590669677,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)):

```cpp
// C++ Standard Library
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// 3rd party libraries
#include "CLI/CLI.hpp"


int main() {
    CLI::App app{"Demonstration app"};

    // Assigning to string for demonstrative purposes
    const std::string help_text = app.help();
    std::cerr << help_text << std::flush;

    return 0;
}
```

yielding:

```
Demonstration app
Usage: [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -h,--help                   Print this help message and exit
```

#### Subcommands

This also works for subcommands
(Compiler Explorer [demo short url](https://godbolt.org/z/a9qnejrja), [demo full url](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:56,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:11,selectionStartColumn:56,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:11),source:%27//+C%2B%2B+Standard+Library%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0A//+3rd+party+libraries%0A%23include+%22CLI/CLI.hpp%22%0A%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++CLI::App+app%7B%22Demonstration+app%22%7D%3B%0A++++CLI::App*+app_sub_command+%3D+app.add_subcommand(%22usage%22,+%22This+is+a+subcommand%22)%3B%0A%0A%0A++++//+Assigning+to+string+for+demonstrative+purposes%0A++++const+std::string+help_text+%3D+app.help()%3B%0A++++std::cerr+%3C%3C+help_text+%3C%3C+std::flush%3B%0A%0A++++std::cerr+%3C%3C+app_sub_command-%3Ehelp()+%3C%3C+std::flush%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:49.736644093303234,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%270%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:clang1000,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:cli11,ver:%27200%27)),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O0+-g+-ggdb+-fsanitize%3Daddress,undefined+%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+clang+10.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.26335590669677,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)):

```cpp
    CLI::App* app_sub_command = app.add_subcommand("usage", "This is a subcommand");
    std::cerr << app_sub_command->help() << std::flush;
```

which yields:

```
This is a subcommand
Usage: usage [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -h,--help                   Print this help message and exit
```

### When was this introduced?

The function signature of `App::help` came to be on commit `952f291`, in April of 2018.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer my own question so that it may help someone else in the future.

I ran across a code snippet on the net that hinted at a solution and lead me to an answer. In short, there is no CLI11 method to directly print out the help text. However, there are two ways to print the help text programmatically.

**try/catch block**

This the CLI11 native method. After you have set up all your option definitions, define a try/catch block as in:

```
CLIx::App app( argc,
               argv );
         .
         .
         .
try
    {
    app.parse( argc,
               argv);
    }
catch( const CLI::CallForHelp &e )
    {
    exit( app.exit( e ) );
    }
```

The line "exit( app.exit( e ) );" calls the app parser method "exit" which prints the help text and returns an errorcode to exit the program. Then when you want help text printed, simply do a throw:

```
throw CLI::CallForHelp();
```

This exception is never described in any if the documentation, and is only discovered by crawling through CLI11's source.

**sort of directly, slightly clumsy**

The previous method assumes you want to exit the program after printing the help text. In my case that wouldn't work since I have users entering commands with options at an interactive prompt as part of my program. Instead, you can call CLI11's exit method directly with a fake exception:

```
app.exit( CLI::CallForHelp() );
```

Kind of goofy, but gets the job done.

Again, nowhere is this documented anywhere and is only discover by going through the CLI11 code.

Lastly, despite this little wart, I highly recommend [CLI11](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11). It's easy to use and quite powerful.

Answer (score 0):

When I use `app.parse(argc, argv)` in my source code, `./myproj -h` error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CLI::CallForHelp'
  what():  This should be caught in your main function, see examples
```

When I use MACROS `CLI11_PARSE` in my source code, no error for `./myproj -h`

```
CLI11_PARSE(app, argc, argv);
```